# How can I deserialize JSON in C#?

Tags: json, c#-4.0, deserialization

Can somebody help me with the proper way to deserialize json in this format:

```
[
    {person: {name: "James", age:26}},
    {person: {name: "Mary", age:36}},
    {person: {name: "Kofi", age:46}}
]
```

The code I'm using is below:

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("url");
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

string json;

using (var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
{
    json = sr.ReadToEnd();
}

var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

var persons= serializer.Deserialize<List<response>>(json);

foreach (var item in persons)
{
    Console.Write("name:" + item.name + " and age: " + item.age);
}
```

The class I'm mapping to is below:

```
public class person
{
    public string name{get;set;}
    public int age{get; set;}
}

public class response
{
   public person person {get;set;}
}
```

I keep getting nulls and empty strings for the name and age properties when I run this code. I would appreciate it a lot if someone could help me out.

Comment: You are mapping to the person class, but in your deserializer you use the "auto" class?

Comment: are you sure this is valid JSON? I think you need more `"` around things like `"person"`

Comment: http://jsonlint.com/ seems to agree with me

Comment: I had to make call item.person.name and item.person.age in the foreach loop

Comment: possible duplicate of [Json Deserialize C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7895105/json-deserialize-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to make call item.person.name and item.person.age in the foreach loop and make sure all properties in the person class were of type string.

Answer (score 5):

It's also possible with the use of the build-in [DataContractJsonSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) class. See example:

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("url");
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
{
   Type serializationTargetType = typeof(List<person>);
   DataContractJsonSerializer jsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(serializationTargetType);

   List<person> jsonDeserialized = (List<person>)jsonSerializer.ReadObject(stream);
}
```

Comment: This won't work. The JSON structure shown by the OP doesn't represent an array of `person`. So using `person[]` as type will crash the serializer.

Answer (score 3):

## Solution

My solution is very easy but you must have installed:

- [NuGet Package Manager](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/27077b70-9dad-4c64-adcf-c7cf6bc9970c/)
- [JSON.NET by Newtonsoft](http://nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json)

[image: nuget]
[image: json]

## Example

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

var url = "http://your-url";
var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person[]>(new WebClient().DownloadString(url));

List<Person> users = new List<Person>();

foreach (var user in json)
{
    users.Add(new Person()
    {
        name = user.name,
        age = user.age
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could define models that will reflect your JSON structure:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

public class Row
{
    public Person Person { get; set; }
}
```

and then deserialize to an array of rows:

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var rows = serializer.Deserialize<Row[]>(json);
foreach (var row in rows)
{
    Console.Write("name: {0} and age: {1}", row.Person.Name, row.Person.Age);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If what's you need is to deserialize a response from a web server I would use some framework that does all of this together.

I've used http://restsharp.org/ and it works great.