# asp consume json data empty result

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I have REST web service with gives me json data, I consume that json data from android, Now I want to consume it from ASP, I tried this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // corrected to WebRequest from HttpWebRequest
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:8080/test2/eattel/cities");

        request.Method = "GET";
        request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";



        //get response-stream, and use a streamReader to read the content
        using (Stream s = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(s))
            {
                var jsonData = sr.ReadToEnd();
                //decode jsonData with javascript serializer
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I got empty page, why please? how to solve it? maybe I am getting the result but i am not printing it? thanks in advance

Comment: What do you get when you navigate to `http://localhost:8080/test2/eattel/cities` in your browser?

Comment: I get 14 city, with name and ID for each one

Comment: @I4V I can consume the JSON from my android project

Comment: it could be a security violation

Comment: I don\t know, how to know please?

Comment: @user2387331 `no answer ?`. Yes, since i was reading other questions too. i didn't know you are in hurry :)

Comment: @I4V sorry ......... please help

Comment: Have you tried `Response.Write(sr.ReadToEnd());` ? From what I see, you only save the JSON data in a variable but you don't do anything with it.

Comment: @user2387331 download [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/). Watch what your browser sends and add that data to the headers of webclient. it may be `User-Agent`, `content-type`, `accept` etc.

Comment: @Kenneth when I used ur code, I got nothing printed also

Comment: @I4V so the code right? it maybe the wrong something else? I just have this class in my whole project

Comment: Could you put a breakpoint on that line and see what the value of `jsonData` is after you call `sr.ReadToEnd()`?

Comment: @Kenneth but when I put `Response.Write("STOP");` before `using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(s))` , the browser prints `STOP`

Comment: @Kenneth at that line should i put break point or at `Response.Write(sr.ReadToEnd());` ?

Comment: You should put in your original line and put a breakpoint on the line after that.

Comment: @Kenneth sorry it is not null, when i put break point i got big exception starts at `Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.CSharp, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The handle is invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070006 (E_HANDLE))`

Comment: I still have 2 mega byte to use, if i don't show up, that means i passed my limit, sorry and thank you

Answer (score 1):

Not truly an answer to this, but something I suggest to anyone working with JSON in .NET - ServiceStack (http://www.servicestack.net/mythz_blog/?p=344)

Check this other StackOverflow: [How can I deserialize JSON in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11665252/how-can-i-deserialize-json-in-c)

Comment: If it's not really an answer, it should go in the comments